# 20.04LTS Update - Cannot Install

Tags: updates

I am running 18.04LTS but I cannot upgrade to 20.04LTS using either the updater or the command line.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the command you are using on the command line. And all the output/warnings or errors you get.  Is your system fully up to date?  Do you have the Hardware Enablement Stack installed?

Comment: The 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS upgrade doesn't enable until **after** the release of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (usually the following week, the release date is  the ISO release for new installs, upgrades are enabled after that date).  ETA is after 23-July-2020 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule)

Comment: @guiverc is right BUT you can always force the upgrade via the command line. NOT recommended. Please tell us all what command you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Classic Upgrading to 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS will be available in July.

However, according to [this page](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today), you can upgrade to the 20.04 with

```
sudo apt update
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Although you specify the -d (development) argument, it will upgrade to the 20.04 stable version. It's just because the classic way to upgrade will wait the 20.04.1 version, in July (Because LTS version is for people who wants really stable system).

Make sure to have a clean upgrade before

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
reboot
```

Comment: No, this gets you the development release.

Comment: @heynnema it will gets you to the 20.04 update, and this will NOT gets you to the 20.10 development release until 20.04.1 is released, next July. Therefore, your downvoted is not justified and my answer is correct. It has been tested just today, at noon, by someone else "g00ny". See there (might need Google translate the page) : https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2053206

Comment: Please see https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today

Comment: @heynnema that's exactly the page I've linked in my original answer, which says to add the `-d` flag

Comment: In the middle of the page, it shows a window that says "development version of focal...". There's been some debate about this, and I think the final conclusion was for 18.04 users to wait until July.

Comment: I changed the down vote.

Comment: It says if the user is not __confortable__ with this, bypassing the proposal to upgrade, and using CLI tools, they might be waiting. But it never says it gets you to the development version. I should know because I, myself, upgraded in that way late April, as g00ny in the link I provided sooner. Still, it doesn't make my answer wrong, it simply answers the question (which include CLI)